# Авторизация средствами PHP, наподобие как у .htaccess

Tags: sqlite3, .htaccess, php

Доброго времени суток.

Извините что на пальцах объясняю...
Граничил доступ пользователей к папке через .htaccess и .hpasswd. Авторизация происходит через какую-то специальную программу, которой у меня, к сожалению, нет. Сейчас нужно перетащить все учётки пользователей в базу SQlit.

В какую сторону копать, чтобы логины и пароли тянулись через .htaccess из базы?
Насколько прочитал, .htaccess не понимает переменных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Авторизация, о которой вы пишите – HTTP авторизация. Её можно [реализовать средствами php](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.http-auth.php) – там есть примеры. Для проверки предоставленной юзером пары логин-пароль уже обращайтесь к своей БД.

И **не забудьте убрать** из `.htaccess` строки про авторизацию:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0):

Распарсите файл .htpasswd и внесите записи из него в таблицу бд.

Там все данные пользователей хранятся построчно в виде login:password_hash. по умолчанию - пароль зашифрован в md5.